# MSSQL - Making multiple count distinct calls in a query runs slowly

Tags: sql-server, performance, distinct

I have tables with the following schema:

### Device

- DeviceId
- Name

### Service

- ServiceId
- Name

### Software

- SoftwareId
- Name

### Device_Software

- DeviceId
- SoftwareId
- DiscoveryDate

### Device_Service

- DeviceId
- ServiceId
- DiscoveryDate

Now, I'm trying to write a query that gives the a Device, and the number of distinct software and services that device has.

If I run the following query I get a result back within 5 seconds (device has 50,000 rows, software and service both have 200 and the link tables include a link for every device to every software and service. Just for testing purposes).

```
SELECT
  device.name
  ,COUNT(DISTINCT(device_software.softwareId))
FROM
  device
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  device_software ON device.deviceId = device_software.deviceId
GROUP BY device.name
```

But if I try to expand the query to include the counts for both, it takes much much longer (~30 minutes and still going):

```
SELECT
  device.name
  ,COUNT(DISTINCT(device_software.softwareId))
  ,COUNT(DISTINCT(device_service.serviceId))
FROM
  device
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  device_service ON device.deviceId = device_service.deviceId
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  device_software ON device.dDeviceId = device_software.deviceId
GROUP BY device.name
```

Now since this is in a stored procedure, I could just get the two counts individually and combine that, but that seems like a hack. I was wondering if anyone knows of a better way to go about doing this in a single query without having a massive performance hit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try the following and see if it makes difference :

```
SELECT
device.name
a.cntSft, b.cntSrv
FROM device
LEFT JOIN
 ( SELECT deviceId, COUNT(DISTINCT softwareId) as cntSft FROM device_software 
 GROUP BY deviceId) a (ON a.deviceId = device.deviceId)
LEFT JOIN 
( SELECT deviceId, COUNT(DISTINCT serviceId) as cntSrv FROM device_service 
 GROUP BY deviceId) b (ON b.deviceId = device.deviceId);
```

You may also not need `COUNT DISTINCT`, but just `COUNT` with this version of query.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider indexed views on Device_Software and Device_Service:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.v_Device_Software
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
  SELECT DeviceId, SoftwareId, DeviceCount = COUNT_BIG(*)
    FROM dbo.Device_Software
    GROUP BY DeviceId, SoftwareId;
GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX x ON dbo.v_Device_Software(DeviceId, SoftwareId);
GO

CREATE VIEW dbo.v_Device_Service
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
  SELECT DeviceId, ServiceId, DeviceCount = COUNT_BIG(*)
    FROM dbo.Device_Service
    GROUP BY DeviceId, ServiceId;
GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX x ON dbo.v_Device_Service(DeviceId, ServiceId);
GO
```

Now your query becomes:

```
SELECT
  device.name
  ,COUNT(vsoft.DeviceId)
  ,COUNT(vserv.DeviceId)
FROM
  dbo.device
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.v_Device_Service AS vserv
  ON device.deviceId = vserv.DeviceId
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.v_Device_Software AS vsoft
  ON device.deviceId = voft.DeviceId
GROUP BY device.name;
```

There are many restrictions, though, and you should be sure to test the impact this has on your entire workload, not just this one query.